# Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am rather new to Rails, and I am attempting to run an app from my console. When I open up the site, however, I see this error message. Does anyone have any insight on what it means?

When I try running "rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development" I just get:

```
Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

When I try running just "rails db:migrate" or "rake db:migrate" I get:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:600:in `migrate'
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:573:in `check_pending!'
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of `rake db:migrate:status`?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue, **run: bin/rails rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development**

And the issue was raised due to pending migrations, which are created migration files at /db/migrate directory by doing add/remove fields to the existing active record or relation(table) in database.

Migrations are stored as files in the db/migrate directory, one for each migration class. The name of the file is of the form YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_create_products.rb, that is to say a UTC timestamp identifying the migration followed by an underscore followed by the name of the migration. The name of the migration class (CamelCased version) should match the latter part of the file name. For example 20080906120000_create_products.rb should define class CreateProducts and 20080906120001_add_details_to_products.rb should define AddDetailsToProducts. Rails uses this timestamp to determine which migration should be run and in what order, so if you're copying a migration from another application or generate a file yourself, be aware of its position in the order.

Example: 
        $bin/rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts

This will create an empty but appropriately named migration:

```
  class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
    def change
    end
  end
```

If the migration name is of the form "AddXXXToYYY" or "RemoveXXXFromYYY" and is followed by a list of column names and types then a migration containing the appropriate add_column and remove_column statements will be created.

```
   $ bin/rails generate migration AddPartNumberToProducts part_number:string
```

will generate

```
   class AddPartNumberToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
     def change
       add_column :products, :part_number, :string
     end
   end
```

Referred at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

Goto your app folder and run below mention command:

```
bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran commands

```
# wait until this completes successfully before continuing
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure


sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

and it solved the problem for me.